# Downloading ReportLab PDF with Flask - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, flask, reportlab

I have a function which generates a PDF and I have a Flask website. I would like to combine the two so that when you visit the site, a PDF is generated and downloaded. I am working on combining various bits of code that I don't fully understand. The PDF is generated and downloaded but fails to ever load when I try to open it. What am I missing?

```
import cStringIO
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from flask import make_response, Flask
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def pdf():

    output = cStringIO.StringIO()
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("test.pdf",pagesize=letter)
    Story=[]

    styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
    styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))
    ptext = '<font size=12>test</font>'

    Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Justify"]))

    doc.build(Story)
    pdf_out = output.getvalue()
    output.close()

    response = make_response(pdf_out)
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename='test.pdf"
    response.mimetype = 'application/pdf'
    return response
app.run()
```

Comment: Your code will work if you change this `doc = SimpleDocTemplate("test.pdf",pagesize=letter)` line to `doc = SimpleDocTemplate(output,pagesize=letter)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Flask's [`send_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=send_file#flask.send_file) for serving files:

```
from Flask import send_file
return send_file('test.pdf', as_attachment=True)
```

With `as_attachment=True` you can force the client to download the file instead of viewing it inside the browser.

Comment: @thanks for the catch on the spelling. The file downloads, but gives an error when I try to open it. Also, your `send_file` solution results in an internal server error when I try to open the page. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you post the error messages? Does the download test.pdf file has the same size as the created one in the app's root directory?

Comment: the PDF is 0 KB in size. The one that works is 2 KB. When opening with Adobe Reader, I get the following error message: `Adobe Reader could not open 'test.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).`

Comment: My bad, the browser tricked me yesterday, it showed the file from cache. So the only solution which works for me is the `return send_file('test.pdf')`. The `send_file()` function requires a filename or a file pointer, please try with the filename, it should work now.

Comment: `send_file()` works great to view in the browser. How can I download it?

Comment: Just add `as_attachment=True` arg to force the browser to download the file. I updated my answer as well.